# codeigniter multiple language

Tags: file, codeigniter, config, multiple-languages

How to load multiple languages in config file in codeigniter.I tried to load multiple languages in codeigniter.In codeigniter the default language is english ex.,

```
$config['language'] = 'english';
```

How to proceed to the next step?

Answer (score 0):

I have a language chooser (dropdown) which sets a session value

Then in each controller I read the sesion and load the language
for isntance:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->lang->load('text', $this->session->userdata('language'));
    $this->lang->load('form_validation', $this->session->userdata('language'));
```

}